# How to make y-axis in pyplot chart display two measurements of same value (counts AND percents)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to build a bar chart that shows the utilization of some resources. Let's say characters in a text:

```
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

raw_data = 'data to make example bar chart'
counts = Counter(raw_data)
keys, values = zip(*counts.most_common())
plt.bar(keys, values);
```

This produces the following chart, with absolute counts of characters:
[image: Resulting bar chart]

If I transform values before plotting using for example

```
values = [v/len(raw_data) * 100.0 for v in values]
```

I would get exactly same graph, but value for a would be 20.0 (%).

Question is, could I somehow show two values on y axis?

I saw recipes on how to show two [different functions](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html) of the same value and have scale to the left and right, but here I have one function, just different units of measurement. Could I somehow show two scales without plotting two bar charts?

https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a right y-axis via `ax.twinx()`, give it exactly the same limits as the left y-axis and format the ticks as percentages. The [`PercentFormatter()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter) gets a parameter telling which value corresponds to 100%. In this case, 100% would be all the data in `raw_data`.

```py
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
import numpy as np

raw_data = np.random.choice([*'abcdefghijklmnopqrst'], 200)
counts = Counter(raw_data)
keys, values = zip(*counts.most_common())
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(keys, values, color='turquoise')
ax.margins(x=0.02) # less wasted space left and right
ax.grid(axis='y')

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set_ylim(*ax.get_ylim())
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(len(raw_data)))
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]